# Cannot read the first two columns of a row in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need to read the allcolumns of a row in a gridview. I use the following code to do so.

```
      foreach (GridViewRow row in gridvw.Rows)
      {
          DataRow dr;
          dr = table.NewRow();

          //string str = gridvw.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text;
          for (int i =0; i < row.Cells.Count-1; i++)
          {
              dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("& ", "");
          }
          table.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
```

Am adding all the values to a table. The above code returns nothing for the first 2 columns of each and every row.

Can anybody help on this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Joseph

Comment: What is the content of the first two columns?

Comment: Please fix your `Replace` method text..

Comment: In case you are are not autogenerating the columns,Show your gridview markup too.

Comment: Content is serial no and name

Comment: Soner, even without the replace method it doesnt work

Comment: can you share one image of your gridview

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
       DataGridViewRowCollection rowCollection = dataGridView1.Rows;
        label1.Text = "";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in rowCollection)
        {
            string str = "";

            foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                str += item.Cells[col.ToString()].Value + "  ";

            }
            label1.Text += "\n" + str;
        }
```

Comment: You cannot pass a string to Cells[]